# Stretching SVG to contain elements unstretched

Tags: css, image, svg, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a full window responsive comic layout with it's contents fitting proportionally. Example of what I currently have: https://jsfiddle.net/csroj3dg/

```
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 960 560" preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

I have set the SVG to preserveAspectRatio="none" so it will fill the entire window. But I'm trying to find a way to fill the panels with more SVG images that will keep their own ratios again.

[image: This is what I am trying to achieve]

The 'ball' would obviously be replaced by some illustrations, but it's just a little example.

I'm not even sure if using a SVG layout is actually the correct way to do it, but I couldn't find a way to do it purely in CSS.

A guess is that somehow I should have to place an SVG image in the #Panel-1 for example so it would function as a clippath. But I searched around and cannot find an example of how to achieve that.

Comment: Awesome project, hope I could help you. I've been trying for an hour or so, with no success :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the element is inside the SVG, it is affected by the scaling applied to the SVG.  The only way around that are some hacky type solutions:

1. Put the circle in another separate SVG that does not have any transform applied to it.
2. Use JS to determine the scale applied to the parent SVG, then apply an inverse scale transform to the circle.  This is a little tricky because it needs to correct the distortion to the shape of the circle, but without affecting its new position.

Comment: Hmm I've tested around a little more, but it seems that is the way I should approach it indeed. Thanks for the suggestion! I'll accept this as helpful! :D